# Should I use the Android Market for this situation?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm developing a app for a public company in Brazil. I've never published something in the android market. This app must only be used by the people that work in this company, I would like to use the android market because the way that updates are done in the app. My question is if there is any way to block others people to download the app from the android market, you have to make login in the app, but I'm afraid of reverse engineering or something like that. Should or Shouldn't I use the Android Market for this situation?

Comment: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2012/12/a-new-way-to-distribute-your-internal.html

Comment: You can allow your app to be downloaded in your country only from google play. Above that you can write some code in you app that it will grant access only to those who a key or a passcode.

Comment: As an alternative to @RobertHarvey's idea, and if you do not have a Google Apps for Business account, you can create a Google+ community and in the Play Store developer console you are able to publish an app so only people who are part of the G+ community can see it. This is a popular method for a lot of developers who do public Alpha/Beta tests.